# Get values from serializeArray with a type array input

Tags: jquery, serializearray

I have inputs like this:

```
<input name="val[test]" value="...">
```

I am trying to get all values with a jQuery's serializeArray, but it wont work.

I am doing:

```
var test = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
debug(test.val[test]);
```

Its not working, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var test = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
$.each(test, function(index, val) {
  console.log( val.test );
});
```

#### Note

`serializeArray()` give the output like:

```
[
 {
   test: 1
 },
 {
   test: 2
 },
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
console.log( test[ index ] );
```

Comment: SOrry, the debug() is a function I have thats it is = to console.log